# error: "bzip2 library and headers are required" while installing R-3.6.0 in opensuse 12.1

Tags: linux, opensuse, r

I want to install R version 3.6.0 in opensuse 12.1 using the tar.gz file. While running `./configure` I am getting error

`checking for BZ2_bzlibVersion in -lbz2... no
checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required`

The configure file of R-3.6.0 requires bzip2 version >=1.0.6. I have bzip2 version 1.0.6 already installed. 
How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Install the `libbz2-devel` package, it has the header files.